# What is the best way to define multiple configs in a multi-build Vue js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

I am working on a Vue 3 web application that would be built and deployed for multiple customers. Each customer has its own title, logo, icon, etc.
What I need is to build the app for every customer with its specific information (let's say showing customer info in `TheFooter.vue` component).
The important requirement is that when the app is going to be built for a customer, other customers' information MUST not be included in the final built files (I mean `/dist` folder after running `npm run build`) for privacy reasons.

The ways I tried:

1. create a customers.js file and export an object like this:

```
const customers = {
  CUSTOMER_A: {
    title: 'Customer A',
    logo: 'assets/customer_a_logo.png',
    // other privacy related data
  },
  CUSTOMER_B: {
    title: 'Customer B',
    logo: 'assets/customer_b_logo.png',
    // other privacy related data
  }
export default const customer[process.env.VUE_APP_CURRENT_CUSTOMER]
```

then in the `.env` file, create a `VUE_APP_CURRENT_CUSTOMER` key with a value like `CUSTOMER_A`, `CUSTOMER_B`,...
And in `TheFooter.vue` import customer data like this:
`const customer = require('./customers.js').default`
but this way I analyzed final built js in `/dist` folder and other cusotmers' information were available.

2. Based on [Vue CLI modes](https://next.cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html), for every customer create a `.env.customer_x` file and add customer-specific data in it, then when building app refers to the current customer with `--mode` flag (e.g. `vue-cli-service build --mode customer_x`). If customers are too many, we would end up with too many .env.customer_... files. (Any other caveats for this solution?)
3. Create a json file (e.g. customers.json) and use it in `TheFooter.vue` like this:
   `import { process.env.VUE_APP_CURRENT_CUSTOMER } from './customers.json'`
   But it seems it is not possible to use variable inside import statement, and I need to use env variables (for ci/cd pipeline)

Is there any idea or best practices for this issue?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically a two step process to generate multiple builds.

#### Step 1: Custom script build

Write a custom build script that will programmatically invoke Webpack. Something like this:

```
// build.js file
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Your webpack.config.js should export a function instead of config.
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

// You can require this data from other `customers.js` file.
const customers = [
  { title: 'App 1' },
  { title: 'App2' }
];

customers.forEach((customer) => {

  // Get webpack configuration for this customer.
  const config = webpackConfig(customer);

  // Invoke the webpack
  webpack(config, (err) => {
    /** Handle error here */
  });

});
```

Your Webpack config would be wrapped in a callback function:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = (customer) => {

  // This function will be called from build.js file.
  
  return {
    entry: 'index.js',
    output: { 
      // ...
    }
    // ...other webpack configuration
  };
};
```

#### Step 2: Data injection

Use Webpack [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) or some other means to inject this data into your actual JavaScript code. For the HTML pages, you can use `webpack-html-plugin` that can also supports this feature using templates. You will need this to set `<title>` and other HTML metadata for your customer's build.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  CUSTOMER_DATA: JSON.stringify(customer)
});
```

Further, this build script should be optimized to deal with `async` and also ensure that output directory is adjusted appropriately for each customer.

As an additional enhancement, Webpack also supports **array configuration** ([multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations)) for creating multiple builds. You can use that as it provides parallel builds out-of-box and without needing separate `build.js` file. I personally like to keep things separate/modular and thus explained that way.

The key to understand here is that in your actual code, you should **nowhere** import this `customers.js` file. It is a build time thing and should be imported in build time scripts only.

Comment: DefinePlugin solved my issue nicely :)